# how to filter a listView in an Activity

Tags: android

i want to filter the tasks to show by what the user will choose in the check boxes,but when i run this code there is an error. 
this is the functions in the filter activity

```
enter code here
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);
    INITIALIZE();
    DONE();
}

public void INITIALIZE()
   {

Go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
ProH=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.pro1);
ProM=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.pro2);
ProL=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.pro3);
Finished=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.finished);
NotFinished=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.notfinished);
Past=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.past);
Future=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.future);

}
public void DONE()
{
final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
Go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if((proH==1&&proM==1)||(proM==1&&proL==1)||(proH==1&&proL==1))
        {
            alertbox.setTitle("Error!");
            alertbox.setMessage("Please Choose one Priority");
            alertbox.setNeutralButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
             alertbox.show();
             ProH.setChecked(false);
             ProM.setChecked(false);
             ProL.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});}}
```

what it the error here?

Comment: You should share the error you're seeing. What does logcat say?

Comment: 01-24 21:51:33.931: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 21:51:33.931: E/AndroidRuntime(309): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.todolist.FILTER }
01-24 21:51:33.931: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
01-24 21:51:33.931: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
01-24 21:51:33.931: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)

Comment: this is part of the error, but when i click on l filter button in the main activity to open this activity it forse quit

Comment: show your main activity.

Comment: Filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent filter=new Intent("com.example.todolist.FILTER");
    startActivity(filter);
    finish();
   }
  });
 }

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your error in the comments, the problem is you're using an Intent that isn't caught by any intent-filter.

"No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.todolist.FILTER }"

Fix your intent-filters, or launch your FilterActivity a different way.

You can explicitly launch Activities with something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FilterActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Where 'context' might be your Activity (this)

Comment: how to launch my FilterActivity a different way.??

Comment: Here's a good page to read through:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html